# How to define scrolling page with ImageView, TextView and ExtendableListView in same layout?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have an Activity which is displaying an assortment of details about a particular widget. There is an image, a TextView for a description, some common stats in TextViews, and then a 
variable sized list of categorised items, from 1 to hundreds.

Quick wireframe: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rxFUf.png

My first assumption was to use a ScrollLayout containing all of these elements: ImageView, TextViews, ExtendableListView, which works only if I specify a height for the ExtendableListView. Since the height is variable this is not a solution. I'm also now aware it's not recommended to use ListViews inside ScrollLayouts.

So I'm stuck. Can anyone point me toward the best way to achieve this kind of layout?

Comment: Maybe use some parent Layout for all those components, and specify height/width for that layout.

Comment: I think that will result in the same situation. The list at the bottom scrolls within itself, taking up whatever space is available below the other elements rather than expanding the parent scrolllayout causing that to scroll. It works if I set a height on the list, but then only until the number of items causes the list to exceed the height I set. Then it scrolls within itself again.

Comment: How about ExpandableListView ? Its scrollable by default, i just don't know if it will satisfy your needs for different components.

Comment: I've got an ExpandableListView in the layout already, thats the list I'm giving a height. I'm not sure how I could include the other items within that view. Aha, perhaps this is what a list header is for?

Comment: Maybe you can do something there, but you will have to use custom view extending ExpandableListView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put expandable list view as main component, and then put the header into the list. addHeaderView()

Comment: I figured that was it, but your answer gave me confidence it was the right direction. Just got it working, and it's exactly what I needed. Thanks.